# In HIVE How do we define Not NULL column in Create table statment?

Tags: model, hive

I have an RDBMS table which I want to convert into HIVE create table statement.
In DDL there are few Not Null columns. How do we define a column as Not Null column in HIVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not implemented yet

**1**
current status: PATCH AVAILABLE

**2**

> As with PK and FK constraints, currently we do not enforce them; thus,
>   the constraints need to use the DISABLE option, but they will be
>   stored and can be enabled for rewriting/optimization using RELY.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16575